# Do I still need to use htmlentities if I'm using HTMLPurifier?

Tags: php, html, security, xss, htmlpurifier

I've been 'sprinkling'

```
htmlentities($user_input, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
```

throughout my views, everywhere I echo data that a user had the chance to enter in my app.

This is very tedious and I'm wondering if using HTMLPurifier in my controllers would be a safe substitute to using `htmlentities` in every `echo` on the view.

I've noticed that HTMLPurifier alone will, for example, try to close an open `<div>` instead of removing it, so if some smartass entered his name as `Johnny<div>` and I `echo` it in my view, it breaks my entire layout.

But if instead I use `htmlentities` alone I get

```
Johnny<div>
```

and my layout is preserved.

So I'm wondering if this is an issue with HTMLPurifier config or if the best practice is to use it in tandem with `htmlentities`.

I understand HTMLPurifier has other functions re compliance and valid HTML, but I'm mostly concerned with XSS.

What do you think?

Comment: About that 'sprinkling': make it a short wrapper function `html("text")` or just `h()`. Security is best achieved by simplicity, not by syntax overhead.

Comment: +1, was planning on creating a helper function for this, and calling it from views instead of using the full syntax above on every single `echo`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are concerned about XSS then use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) (there's no reason to use the full-blown `htmlentities` for that) and you are golden:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($user_input);
```

HTMLPurifier is only meaningful if you want to allow *some* HTML capability while still preventing XSS. But as any other piece of code, there's the possibility that it might not work as advertised at some point. Personally, I wouldn't go there.

**Update:**

Yes, `htmlspecialchars` does support additional flags (including `ENT_QUOTES`). However, `ENT_QUOTES` is *only* needed if:

- you are outputting the value of an HTML attribute **and**
- you have enclosed the value inside *single* quotes

So for example, you would **not** need `ENT_QUOTES` here:

```
<p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($input); ?></p>
```

or here:

```
<p id="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($input); ?>"></p>
```

You *would* need it here:

```
<p id='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($input, ENT_QUOTES); ?>'></p>
```

Comment: any flags on `htmlspecialchars`? I wonder if `ENT_QUOTES` is necessary for added security

Answer (score 2):

Different purposes. HP is for cleaning HTML, so that users can actually submit HTML which is to be used as actual HTML.

If you expect text, and don't want to use it as HTML, then generally `htmlspecialchars`. It's particular suited for text strings that might end up in tag attributes somehow.

If you want to display only text, then you should even prefer the combo:

```
 htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($input), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")
```

(Then obviosuly HP wouldn't make sense. `strip_tags()` is in fact by itself sufficient for XSS prevention, **as long as** that content is output in a text node only, not in any attributes.)

Comment: is there a performance hit using `htmlentities` instead? - why is everyone so much more in favor of `htmlspecialchars`?

Comment: Not measureably so. `ENT_QUOTES` again is only necessary if the content would end up within tags, in attribute context.

Comment: yes, that is the case, some user data may be in attributes in my app, also within jQuery strings

Comment: Then you need. Additionally `json_encode` if any of this ends up in JS context. (Sometimes alternatively. Not for you.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to be able to write HTML, then HTMLPurifier seems to be a good solution -- but from what you're writing, it seems you don't want and need the user to enter HTML, and in that case, it's no solution at all (as you mention, it allows e.g. a div element).

HtmlEntities, on the other hand, escapes the user input, so it's the way to go for most XSS and blocking HTML. However, note that htmlEntities will not protect you against all XSS attacks. For example, if you use single quotes around HTML attributes and allow user input to be inserted into attribute values, then a malicious user can attack you by passing a ' single quote character, thus escaping your quote. To avoid this, you need to use the ENT_QUOTES option. Others at PHP.net have mentioned that special care also needs to be given to double dashes within a comment.

Comment: thx philipp - my app is not designed for the user to submit HTML, so you are correct HTMLPurifier does not seem to be the way to go

Comment: `is not designed` does not mean HTML won't be submitted (maliciously).